# Matlab symbolic tooltip; trying to design a 3rd order sallen key filter

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing

Trying to design a 3rd order sallen key filter using matlab:

```
[B,A]=cheby1(3,1,10*10^6*2*pi,'s');

%3rd order sallen key
syms R1 R2 R3 R4 R5 C1 C2 C3
M=1+R4/R5;
num=[M/(R1*R2*R3*C1*C2*C3)];
den=[1 (1/(R1*C1)+1/(R2*C1)+1/(R2*C2)+(1-M)/(R3*C3)+1/(R3*C2)) ((C3*R3+R1*C3+R2*C3+C1*R1+(1-M)*(R1+R2)*C2)/(R1*R2*R3*C1*C2*C3)) (1/(R1*R2*R3*C1*C2*C3))];

solve('B=num','A=den','M=5','R1','R2','R3','R4','R5')
```

It tells me:

```
Warning: 3 equations in 5 variables. New variables might be introduced.  
Warning: Explicit solution could not be found.
```

`cheby1` gives you a transfer function (numerator and denominator) for a chebyshev type 1 filter; I'm then trying to equate it to the form of the transfer function of a 3rd order sallen key filter; and get matlab to solve for the resistor values in terms of the capacitor values.

==> How can I get the solution I want?

To note: this has nothing to do with the actual calculation being performed, and all to do with how to use matlab.

Comment: This is not the right approach to this problem.

Comment: Suggest migrating to dsp.SE or electronics.SE.

Comment: the question is far more about the use of the matlab symbolic toolbox; less about the actual task I'm trying to do.

Comment: @nibot, dsp.SE is still a private beta. Can't migrate there.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I'm missing something, but B is 1x4 vectors, while num is a scalar, so there is no way you're going to get an answer. Also, (*edit*) you can't solve indirect equations from the command window (i.e. `solve('M=5','R1','R2')` won't work, but `solve('1 + R1/R2=5','R1','R2')` will)

Even if you corrected those I suspect that this will be too complicated for the symbolic toolbox (the solution is likely a really high-order polynomial which can't be solved explicitly)

You're best bet is to use [fsolve](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/fsolve.html) to find a numerical solution

Comment: Well, the MuPAD engine isn't really worth anything at all. It can't even solve the equation `M=1+R4/R5` for `R5`. You're right that the best way in this is using a numerical solution.

Comment: @Egon MuPad has it's strengths, but there are things it can't do. Humans can't solve general quintic equations, so don't expect software to be any better

Comment: I agree some things aren't soluble symbolically. But if your CAS can't solve such elementary equations as `M=1+R4/R5` (possibly with the constraint that `M=2`, I wouldn't really call that a decent CAS. Even my HP 50g can solve that symbolically.

Comment: @Egon, Matlab can solve that equation... it took me bit rediscover how thou, and MuPAD and the Matlab command prompt require different inputs

Comment: I also noticed that you can't solve those indirect equations in strings. You can however prepare everything outside of strings. You can look at my code on http://pastebin.com/xaFHi3P6 According to the help that should work, but it doesn't. But if you have to manipulate those strings by hand, you can as well do the calculations by hand (or that's my opinion at least).

Comment: Thanks Egon; but that still came out as Warning: Explicit solution could not be found.